# How to run stub-runner docker image with local repo

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I tried to run stub runner docker image with local repo as below,

```
STUBRUNNER_IDS="cn.xxx.accounting:accounting-configserver:1.0.0:stubs:9876"
STUBRUNNER_REPOSITORY_ROOT="file:///m2/repository"
STUBRUNNER_PORT="8083"
SC_CONTRACT_DOCKER_VERSION=2.0.0.RC2
docker run  --rm --interactive --tty -e "STUBRUNNER_IDS=${STUBRUNNER_IDS}" -e "REPO_WITH_BINARIES_URL=${STUBRUNNER_REPOSITORY_ROOT}" -p "${STUBRUNNER_PORT}:${STUBRUNNER_PORT}" -p "9876:9876" -v ~/.m2:/m2  springcloud/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner:"${SC_CONTRACT_DOCKER_VERSION}"
```

Then I got below error,

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]:
>   Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No stubs were found on classpath for
>   [cn.xxx.accounting:accounting-configserver]

Looks like stub runner is using classpath to find the stub. How to change the stub mode to local? I can not find the source of dockerfile of `spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner`. Any env does that tricky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's enough to attach the volume of your local .m2 to the one in the container. Also you need to pass the `STUBRUNNER_STUBS_MODE=REMOTE` (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerProperties.java#L100)

```
#!/bin/bash

SC_CONTRACT_DOCKER_VERSION="${SC_CONTRACT_DOCKER_VERSION:-1.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT}"
APP_IP="$( ./whats_my_ip.sh )"

# Stub coordinates 'groupId:artifactId:version:classifier'
STUB_GROUP="${STUB_GROUP:-com.example}"
STUB_ARTIFACT="${STUB_ARTIFACT:-bookstore}"
STUB_VERSION="${STUB_VERSION:-0.0.1.RELEASE}"
STUB_PORT="9876"

# Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner properties
STUBRUNNER_PORT="${STUBRUNNER_PORT:-8083}"
STUBRUNNER_IDS="${STUB_GROUP}:${STUB_ARTIFACT}:${STUB_VERSION}:stubs:${STUB_PORT}"
STUBRUNNER_REPOSITORY_ROOT="http://${APP_IP}:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local"

docker run  --rm -e "STUBRUNNER_IDS=${STUBRUNNER_IDS}" -e "SERVER_PORT=${STUBRUNNER_PORT}" -e "STUBRUNNER_REPOSITORY_ROOT=${STUBRUNNER_REPOSITORY_ROOT}" -p "${STUBRUNNER_PORT}:${STUBRUNNER_PORT}" -p "${STUB_PORT}:${STUB_PORT}"  -v ~/.m2:/root/m2 springcloud/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner:"${SC_CONTRACT_DOCKER_VERSION}"
```

Notice that we're using the maven local or our docker image but it points to `${USER_HOME}/.m2` that AFAIR is `/root/.m2` in Docker.

Comment: Looks like [the sample in doc](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.0.0.RC2/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_example_of_client_side_usage_in_a_non_jvm_project) miss required env **STUBRUNNER_STUBS_MODE=REMOTE** due to the repo of sample is remote url. 

Also the source repo of docker image `springcloud/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner` does not link to hub.docker.com, it might help to find it out if checking the dockerfile or entrypoint scripts.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it does. Can you file an issue p please? I'll try to update the docs today

Comment: check [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/666)

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I have a stubs jar and springcloud/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner docker image. I don't want it to run locally. So there is any way I can combine both the things in an image and run a single image by command docker run imageName?